# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}x \,dx$ using complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to evaluate the following integral, using complex integration:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d}x.$$ I know the solution is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, as given by the exercise.

It is hinted that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}x} - 1}{x}\mathrm{d}x,$$ and that I'm supposed to use the indented semicircle as my toy contour.

Yet, I don't know how to go from here or approach this problem. Can I show the hint by using Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: This is a big duplicate. Try googling this exact question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980970/how-to-calculate-int-limits-infty-infty-fraceixxdx)